# ggplot2 - changing numeric axis title to vector of strings

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, label, axis

So far I have the following from my ggplot compilation:

[image]

And I got the axis just right this time ... with the following code snippet:

```
p<- p + ylim(c(0,100))
p<- p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0))

p<- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(1940,1985,by=5)))
p
```

so I have an **x-axis from 1940-1985 by steps of 5** and a **y-axis from 0-100 by steps of 20** ...

## The first question

How do I make the 100 appear on the y-axis?

## The second question

How do I change my x-labels into the following string vectors?

```
abbrev_x <- c("1940","'45","'50","'55","'60","'65","'70","'75","'80","'85")
abbrev_y <- c("0","20","40","60","80","100%")
```

So, the best solution I've found revolves around `scale_x_continuous`, which the following code snippet example suggests work with already pre-existing string axis labels:

```
p + scale_x_discrete(limit = c("I1", "SI2", "SI1"),
                 labels = c("Ione","SItwo","SIone"))
```

[image]

This is certainly an issue, as what I want to write is the following:

```
abbrev_x <- c("1940","'45","'50","'55","'60","'65","'70","'75","'80","'85")
abbrev_y <- c("0","20","40","60","80","100%")
p<- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = abbrev_x)
p<- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = abbrev_y)
p
```

But this seems to be a fictitious reality in my world right now. To justify this fiction, here is the following error code, among others as I tweak:

```
Error in x - from[1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

You need two parameters to label continuous axis correctly:

- *breaks*: specify where to place the labels
- *labels*: specify what labels to put on axis

in the *scale_x/y_continuous* function:

*Example data frame*:

```
df <- data.frame(YearOfBirth = seq(1940,1985,by=5), AverageProbability = runif(10) * 100)

abbrev_x <- c("1940","'45","'50","'55","'60","'65","'70","'75","'80","'85")
abbrev_y <- c("0","20","40","60","80","100%")

ggplot(df, aes(x = YearOfBirth, y = AverageProbability)) + 
    geom_line(col = "burlywood3") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1940,1985,by=5), labels = abbrev_x) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = (0:5)*20, labels = abbrev_y, limits = c(0, 110))
```

[image]

Comment: I get a blank graph with no data lines on it anymore when I use that snippet suggested. Does using `labels="..."` change the data content in my ggplot?

Comment: Your actual data may lie outside the range I am using here, I am assuming your probability goes from 0 to 1. Didn't notice your data goes from 0 to 100. `labels = ...` doesn't change the data content, it changes how the axis is labeled.

Comment: My friend, you're an absolute hero.

Comment: Another question, if I wanted to add some text in above the curve that's blue, and text below the curve that is yellow, kind of like: Age30 and Age40. How do you add raw text to the curve like that? Not sure how to do it 1 for each curve

Comment: Normally, you would add another group variable such as age in the mapping i.e. `aes(...)`, this gives you label as *legend*. you can also use `geom_text()`. But I would not answer the question here in too much detail since it has become another question. If you want to get answers, I suggest you firstly search google for doing this and if you can't get the answer, you can ask another question.